# Select lines that matches a set of prefixes

Tags: mysql, string

I want to select numbers that begins either with `36` or `375` but not the others in this table:

```
+-------------+
| phone       |
+-------------+
| 36000000000 |  <
| 37000000001 |
| 36000000002 |  <
| 37500000002 |  <
| 34000000002 |
| 33000000002 |
+-------------+
```

I've tried :

```
select phone from numbers where phone in ( "36%", "375%" );
```

but it returns an empty set, I guess the wildcard `%` does not work with the `in` function

In my case, I've a lot of prefixes to test, that's why I didn't use the `like` operator

Comment: Are the list of prefixes in the database, or are they being hardcoded into the query?

Comment: USING in will not work, as in performs a literal match. Therefore in "column in (1,2)" is equivalent to "(column = 1 or column = 2)".

Comment: @user814064 yes, it's hardcoded into the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via single regex:

```
SELECT phone FROM numbers WHERE phone REGEXP '^(36*|375*)'
```

that still requires some operations (i.e. recounting prefixes), but is shorter than `OR LIKE` syntax.

Now as for indexes. Old version of MySQL will not use index for both cases - `OR LIKE` (because of `OR`) and `REGEXP`.  But new versions (I've tested on 5.5) will use index for *both cases* - see [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c484/2). Edit: *may be* `OR LIKE` will use index in older version of MySQL, than `REGEXP` - that remains to be checked (in comments below we've found that 5.1 version used index for `OR LIKE`. `REGEXP` used index for 5.5)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson LIKE will use it, yes (and only if it is left subsring, i.e. LIKE '36%'), but OR LIKE will not - even if members are left substrings - that because of OR in condition. So in that case REGEXP and OR LIKE are the same. To be more specific, new versions of MySQL can handle that (i.e. use index even with `OR LIKE`), but in common case - no.

Comment: [EXPLAIN tells me that it does](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b2018/1), and I'd hardly call 5.1 recent :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - yes, it's because of new version of MySQL, I guess. That will result for `REGEXP` as used index too. 5.1 is not very old version (better to check on 5.0.x)

Comment: Thanks @AlmaDoMundo I've used: `SELECT phone FROM numbers WHERE phone REGEXP '^(36|375)[0-9]+'` which is smaller in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIKE` instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT phone FROM numbers WHERE phone LIKE "36%" OR phone LIKE "375%"
```

Comment: read the question until the end; I've a LOT of prefixes to test, I want to use something small line the `IN` function